# Python WebHelpers creating upload for multiple files

Tags: python, html, file, web, tags

Python's webhelper (http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/html/tags.html#) doesn't seem to have a multiple file picker. For file upload field it seems to have only one tag : webhelpers.html.tags.file.

Am I missing something? TIA.

:: Sid

Comment: I found the solution. You can simply say :
${tags.file(name="files", multiple=True)}

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Simply do :

${tags.file(name="files", multiple=True)}